# Can't video record through native script on IOS using the nativescript-videorecorder plugin

Tags: javascript, ios, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am trying to record video through nativeScript using the nativeScript-videorecorder plugin. https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-videorecorder

I have initialized the recorder just like it describes in the quickstart for the nativeScript-video recorder.

When I try to start recording by running the startRecording() function of the AdvancedVideoView it doesn't start recording and the following is then outputted to the console

```
<<<< AVCaptureFigVideoDevice >>>> -[AVCaptureFigVideoDevice _copyFigCaptureSourceProperty:]_block_invoke: (0x103a53e00) Copy(AVHEVCSettings) failed (-12784)

<<<< AVCaptureFigVideoDevice >>>> -[AVCaptureFigVideoDevice _copyFigCaptureSourceProperty:]_block_invoke: (0x103a53e00) Copy(AVHEVCSettings) failed (-12784)
<<<< AVCaptureFigVideoDevice >>>> -[AVCaptureFigVideoDevice _copyFigCaptureSourceProperty:]_block_invoke: (0x103a53e00) Copy(AVHEVCSettings) failed (-12784)
```

Any help on what is causing the problem with this issue is appreciated

Comment: Did you acquire necessary permissions to record video (camera & microphone access), try `requestPermissions(..)` method before attempting to record.

Comment: @Manoj yes I did.

Comment: Did you see the permission dialog, after allowing it still returned those errors above?

Comment: @Manoj yes the permissions dialog appeared and I accepted it for the app and I am still getting the errors

Comment: What device you are using for testing & what's the OS version?

Comment: Im testing on an iphone x ios 12.4